# How to get list of indexes of all occurences of the same value in list of lists?

Tags: python

Having a list of lists,

```
mylist = [[1, 3, 4], [3, 6, 7], [8, 0, -1, 3]]
```

I need a method to get list containing indexes of all elements of some certain value, '3' for example. So for value of '3' such list of indexes should be

```
[[0, 1], [1, 0], [2, 3]]
```

Thanks in advance.

**Update**: we can have several instances of sought-for value ('3' in our case) in same sublist, like

```
my_list = [[1, 3, 4], [3, 6, 7], [8, 0, -1, 3, 3]]
```

So desired output will be `[[0, 1], [1, 0], [2, 3], [2, 4]]`.

I suppose that my solution is slightly naive, here it is:

```
my_list = [[1, 3, 4], [3, 6, 7], [8, 0, -1, 3, 3]]
value = 3
list_of_indexes = []

for i in range(len(my_list)):
        for j in range(len(my_list[i])):
            if my_list[i][j] == value:
                index = i, j
                list_of_indexes.append(index)

print list_of_indexes

>>[(0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 3), (2, 4)]]
```

It will be great to see more compact solution

Comment: This question shows a significant lack of research and detail.

Comment: Is this homework or an interview question?

Comment: homework, and I already wrote some ugly code that solves this task. I hope to get more elegant solution

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the value appears once in each sublist, you could use the following function, which makes use of the built in `enumerate` function and a list comprehension:

```
my_list = [[1, 3, 4], [3, 6, 7], [8, 0, -1, 3]]

def func(my_list, x):
    return [[idx, sublist.index(x)] for idx, sublist in enumerate(my_list)]

answer = func(my_list, 3)
print(answer)
```

**Output**

```
[[0, 1], [1, 0], [2, 3]]
```

Comment: Thanks for suggested solution, but lets consider that we have several instances of sought-for value ('3' in our case) in same sublist, like so:

`my_list = [[1, 3, 4], [3, 6, 7], [8, 0, -1, 3, 3]]`

Desired output in this case is `[[0, 1], [1, 0], [2, 3], [2, 4]`

Comment: So you always want to return the last index of the value in the sublist? Your edit isn't entirely clear

Comment: whoops, forgot trailing square bracket. The desired output is of course  `[[0, 1], [1, 0], [2, 3], [2, 4]]`

Comment: Not the bracket. At the moment desired-output is same as input!

Answer (score 0):

Easy way,

```
def get_val(mylist, val):
    for ix, item in enumerate(mylist):
        yield [ix, item.index(val)]

mylist = [[1, 3, 4], [3, 6, 7], [8, 0, -1, 3]]

val = list(get_val(mylist, 3))
print(val)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1], [1, 0], [2, 3]]
```